# Migrating from south to django 1.8 raises table already exists

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a project running on django 1.6 and working to upgrade it to 1.8 which includes moving from south migration to django's migration.

I tried to follow steps mentioned by django documentation on how to update from south to django migrations here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south

& am facing a problem when trying to migrate --initial-fake, it seems like even though some tables exists django migration is trying to create them

```
./manage.py migrate --fake-initial 


Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying retail.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying account.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying default.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 286, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/project-path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "social_auth_association" already exists
```

Any advise please?

regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

The only complication is if you have a circular dependency loop of foreign keys; in this case, makemigrations might make more than one initial migration, and you’ll need to mark them all as applied using:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake yourappnamehere
```

So try to run

```
python manage.py migrate --fake default
```

And it should do the trick.

Comment: but am not facing circular dependency, its passing that point and execution of migration starts and then for some reason it try to create a table that actually exists

Comment: So you get the same error if you apply the migration only for that specific app? Did you perhaps make some changes to the models before running `makemigrations`?

Comment: Actually zanderle, it turned out what you were proposing is correct and worked out, just needed to delete pyc files

Answer (score 6):

Type  `python manage.py migrate --help`

> ```
> --fake         Mark migrations as run without actually running them.
>
> --fake-initial Detect if tables already exist and fake-apply initial
>                migrations if so. Make sure that the current database
>                schema matches your initial migration before using
>                this flag. Django will only check for an existing
>                table name.
> ```